# Pandas: how to use between_time with milliseconds?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Consider this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx2=[pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.000'), 
     pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.200'),
     pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.400')]

test=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,1,3], 'groups' : ['A',np.NaN,'A']},index=idx2)
    test
Out[27]: 
                        groups  value
2016-08-31 22:08:12.000      A      1
2016-08-31 22:08:12.200    NaN      1
2016-08-31 22:08:12.400      A      3
```

I need to only keep data between `22:08:12.200` and `22:08:12.400`, so I naturally use `between_time`:

```
test.between_time('22:08:12.200','22:08:12.400')
```

gives

> ValueError: Cannot convert arg ['22:08:12.200'] to a time

What is wrong here? How can I slice my `dataframe` based on time with millisecond information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure why the direct string does not work, but it looks like something to do with a time conversion from the `datetime` which came from the string.  But you can workaround with an explicit conversion to `time` as:

**Code:**

```
test.between_time(*pd.to_datetime(['22:08:12.200', '22:08:12.400']).time)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx2 = [
    pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.000'),
    pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.200'),
    pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12.400')]

test = pd.DataFrame(
    {'value': [1, 1, 3], 'groups': ['A', np.NaN, 'A']}, index=idx2)

print(test.between_time(
    *pd.to_datetime(['22:08:12.200', '22:08:12.400']).time))
```

**Results:**

```
                        groups  value
2016-08-31 22:08:12.200    NaN      1
2016-08-31 22:08:12.400      A      3
```

Comment: nice! works perfectly.  I wonder what `*` in front of `pd.to_datetime(['22:08:12.200', '22:08:12.400']).time` means here?

Comment: @HCSF https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Answer (score 2):

you can use standard datetime :

```
test.between_time(datetime.time(22,8,12,200000),datetime.time(22,8,12,400000),include_start=True,include_end=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use between_time, you can slice directly on the index.

```
test[(test.index >= '2016-08-31 22:08:12.200') & (test.index <='2016-08-31 22:08:12.400')]
```

For whatever reason, the follwing will NOT work when milliseconds are specified.

```
# doesn't work with milliseconds:
test['2016-08-31 22:08:12':'2016-08-31 22:08:12']
```

Comment: But why doesn't it work with miliseconds? Is it a bug or by design? any open issues?

Comment: Has to be a bug.